# How to add Channel Handler to TCPServer on Channel initialization

Tags: project-reactor, reactor-netty

I have the following code snipped that creates a TCPServer, and attaches a ChannelHandler to the channel in the `doOnChannelInit()` function. The server is to process byte data from an embedded device.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NettyServer {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NettyServer.class);

    private final NettyProperties nettyProperties;

    private final NettyServerHandler nettyServerHandler;

    private TcpServer server;

    public void run() {
        server = TcpServer
                .create()
                .host("localhost")
                .port(nettyProperties.getTcpPort())
                .doOnChannelInit((connectionObserver, channel, remoteAddress) -> {
                    log.info("Connection from " + remoteAddress);
                    channel.pipeline()
                            .addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 4, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                            .addLast(new ByteArrayDecoder())
                            .addLast(new ByteArrayEncoder())
                            .addLast(nettyServerHandler);
                });

        server.bindNow();
        log.info("Server running");
    }

}
```

Channel handler

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class NettyServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<byte[]> {

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NettyServerHandler.class);

    private final AttributeKey<byte[]> dataKey = AttributeKey.valueOf("dataBuf");

    private final AttributeKey<Integer> dataLen = AttributeKey.valueOf("dataBufLen");


    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        log.info("New Meter connection from : " + ctx.channel());
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        if (ctx.channel() != null) {
            log.info(String.format("Meter/Client Disconnected. No: %s ; Channel : %s", meterNo, ctx.channel()));

        }
        ctx.close();

    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, byte[] msg) throws Exception {

        log.info("Message received: " + new String(msg);
        ctx.channel().read();
    }
}
```

I'm able to connect to the server, but when i send a message, nothing happens, the log statements are not triggered.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, would appreciate some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add custom handlers to the Netty pipeline. The example above can be written like this:

```
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class NettyServer {

        Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NettyServer.class);

        private final NettyProperties nettyProperties;

        private TcpServer server;

        public void run() {
            server = TcpServer
                    .create()
                    .host("localhost")
                    .port(nettyProperties.getTcpPort())
                    .doOnChannelInit((connectionObserver, channel, remoteAddress) -> {
                        log.info("Connection from " + remoteAddress);
                        channel.pipeline()
                                .addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 4, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
                    })
                    .handle((in, out) ->
                            in.receive()
                                    .asString()
                                    .doOnNext(s -> log.info("Message received: " + s))
                                    .then());

            server.bindNow();
            log.info("Server running");
        }
    }
```

Consider checking the [Reference Documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_consuming_data)
The incoming data can be transformed to `String` with (`asString`), to `byte[]` with (`asByteArray`) etc. If there is no suitable transformation you can use `map(byteBuf -> ...)` and transform the `ByteBuf` to the needed abstraction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I need to keep a reference to each channel opened as the devices periodically send a heart beat message. I also need to be able to send a message to any of the channels on demand from this server. That's why I felt a custom handler would be required. Can your approach still work for this scenerio?

Comment: You have the channel - in the `handle` method, use `in.withConnection(...)`. Why don't you use `channelGroup` configuration?

Comment: Thanks your original answer solved my initial problem which has now exposed another problem about performing handshake protocol initiated by the server. That's why I need to save each connection/channel. Can you give a guide as to how to use `in.withConnection` and or `channelGroup` to achieve this? The documentation doesn't provide enough information in this regard. Thanks again.